# Unsupported mimetype: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I am using preview-generator to make a Pdf from doc file in Django. The code is working properly in my local machine but the same deployment is not working on the server which is Ubuntu 18.04.

I am getting an error:

`Unsupported mimetype: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

I have researched it and found the libre office needs to be installed in the server and its already present on my server. Can you please suggest what I need to do or how can I define the path of libre office.

I am using `Django` and once I use the shell the file generated properly but in the the web its not working.
This is the error on terminal.

gunicorn[29453]: Builder  is missing a dependency: this builder requires inkscape to be available
gunicorn[29453]: Builder  is missing a dependency: this builder requires convert to be available
Builder  is missing a dependency: this builder requires qpdf to be available
Builder  is missing a dependency: this builder Builder  is missing a dependency: this builder requires libreoffice to be available

Comment: My problem is fixed now. I have removed path from my gunicorn service. :)